# Ghost: Failed at the sqlite3@2.1.19 install script

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, sqlite, ghost-blog

I'm trying to deploy a ghost blog on Ubuntu [following this tutorial](https://digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-host-ghost-with-nginx-on-digitalocean). When I run sudo npm install --production, a problem appears with the sqlite3 package.

```
npm ERR! sqlite3@2.1.19 install: `node build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@2.1.19 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the sqlite3 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node build.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls sqlite3
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I have then run:

```
npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source
```

but another problem appears:

```
> sqlite3@2.1.19 install /srv/data_studio/web/journal.gentlenode.com/node_modules/sqlite3
> node build.js

make: Entering directory `/srv/data_studio/web/journal.gentlenode.com/node_modules/sqlite3/build'
ACTION deps_sqlite3_gyp_action_before_build_target_unpack_sqlite_dep Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3071700/sqlite3.c
TOUCH Release/obj.target/deps/action_before_build.stamp
CC(target) Release/obj.target/sqlite3/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3071700/sqlite3.o
Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3071700/sqlite3.c: In function ‘porter_stemmer’:
Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3071700/sqlite3.c:127208:41: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3071700/sqlite3.c:127212:39: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3071700/sqlite3.c:127225:35: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3071700/sqlite3.c:127230:39: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3071700/sqlite3.c:127236:41: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3071700/sqlite3.c:127241:39: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3071700/sqlite3.c:127250:38: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3071700/sqlite3.c:127257:37: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3071700/sqlite3.c:127300:39: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
Release/obj/gen/sqlite-autoconf-3071700/sqlite3.c:127320:34: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]
```

After that, I can't even rerun sudo npm install --production.

Answer (score 1):

Run these commands:

```
$ sudo npm install -g node-gyp
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
$ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make
```

This installs the things you need to successfully run:

```
$ npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. I had an issue with node version as well, sqlite would not install with node 0.11. Use `n` to switch version if you are in the same trouble. http://www.mattpalmerlee.com/2013/03/23/installing-and-switching-between-multiple-versions-of-node-js-n-vs-nvm/